# Excel formula to work out current DAY from quarter start

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table

I am looking for a formula to work out how many working days have elapsed from the start of the current quarter.

For example

Quarter started on 01/01/2018 until today would be 33 days but then when I would open the spreadsheet up tomorrow it would work out that it is the 34th day and so on till the quarter ends then starts again from 01/04/2018.

This would be part of a formula which works out a daily average based off of the total fixes completed by one person being read from a Pivot Table.

Current formula is as such:

=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("Activity Sub Status",'SL1 Team'!$A$1,"Assigned To","ADAM.MANN","Activity Sub Status","Solved by Phone")/66)

This does work but as you can see it is working out the daily average based on the total days in the current quarters, this shows a very low average.

I have tried to get the data to show as an average directly out the pivot table but it wont show the data, I assume this is down to the way the data is being worked out from the RAW data.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize a simple formula to get the number of days like this:

`=TODAY()-DATE(2018,1,1)` - `DATE(2018,1,1)` = date of start of quarter.

or

`=TODAY()-A1` - `A1` = cell with start of quarter.

You final formula should look something like:

```
=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("Activity Sub Status",'SL1 Team'!$A$1,"Assigned To","ADAM.MANN","Activity Sub Status","Solved by Phone")/(TODAY()-DATE(2018,1,1)))
```

To find the quarter dynamically I'd use the below formula to determine the month the quarter start in, like this:

`(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)-1)*3+1`

You can use this to determine how many days have gone by:

`=DAYS(TODAY(), DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), (ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)-1)*3+1, 1))`

And add it to you formula like the example below:

```
=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("Activity Sub Status",'SL1 Team'!$A$1,"Assigned To","ADAM.MANN","Activity Sub Status","Solved by Phone")/(DAYS(TODAY(), DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), (ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)-1)*3+1, 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula to tell the total days from this quarter:

```
=DAYS(H1, DATE(YEAR(H1), IF(MONTH(H1)<4, 1, IF(MONTH(H1)<7, 4, IF(MONTH(H1)<10, 7, 10))), 1))
```

Where H1 contains the date you want to calculate the days.

Explanation:

- IF(MONTH(H1)<4, 1, IF(MONTH(H1)<7, 4, IF(MONTH(H1)<10, 7, 10)): Returns the first month of the current quarter
- A custom date is formatted using the month, current year and the first day
- The number of days using the DAYS function (today minus the custom date)

Note that it is fully dynamic and will figure out the number of days from today (or any date if desired, just replace the today function in the formula with the cell number)

Comment: Great approx on dynamically finding the quarter, but did you test out your formula over the full year? I'm getting strange values like `=DAYS("01/03/2018", DATE(YEAR("01/03/2018"), (ROUNDDOWN(MONTH("01/03/2018")/3,0)*4)+1, 1))` gives `-61`, and increments `(+1)` until `"30/04/2018" = -1`. This happens throughout the year.

Comment: Ah this is US date style. The first segment of the date is the month, not the second. You will have to adjust the formula according to your locale. Specifically the part where the custom date is.

Comment: As we're using `DATE(MONTH())` that shouldn't matter, I thing the issue is that `(ROUNDDOWN(MONTH("03/01/2018")/3,0)*4)+1` = `(ROUNDDOWN(3/3,0)*4)+1` = `5`, when the corresponding quarter for `"03/01/2018"` should be `1`, `Jan`.

Comment: Never mind. I was a fool. I've put in a corrected formula. Thanks for pointing it out.